# С чего начать изучение ассемблера?

Tags: ассемблер

Зачем? Нужно для чтения ассамблерных листингов кода или использования ассамблерных вставок в C++ или поиск и инджект в память другой программы(в добрых целях). Не планирую написание  под микроконтроллеры или специфические процессоры, хотя кто его знает, но во всяком случае при необходимости можно будет углубиться, а пока не вижу в этом смысла.
Так с чего теперь начать? В гугле советуют книгу "Питер Абель. Ассемблер и программирование для IBM PC", её будет достаточно? А какую среду выбрать под Windows? Что-то я не понял насчет переносимого/непереносимого ассамблера от мелкософта или ещё чего. Вообщем темный лес.

Comment: c петцольда начните, если еще не читали ISBN: 5750201597

Comment: Без обид, но начните с названия

Comment: @DreamChild, а я себя наоборот исправлял с "e" на "a", когда на автомате писал, думал что так правильней:)

Comment: >думал что так правильней:)

эмм..откуда такие мысли?

Comment: @DreamChild, не из википедии точно). Ну мозг такая штука, раз неправильно прочитал и потом нужно будет чтобы кто то исправил, потому что сам ошибки не увидишь, так как кэш есть и зачем мозгу лишние ресурсы на проверку тратить, до первой осознанности конечно или пинка извне.

Comment: @strol кстати, да, мозг - штука любопытная. У меня был похожий "баг" - в английских словах часто встречается сочетание букв **ght** (fli*ght**, ri**ght**, ni**ght** и тд) Где-то увидел ошибочное написание с перепутанными буквами (ni**gth**), после чего стал автоматически делать ошибки в таких словах, переставляя буквы "h" и "t", хотя раньше никогда так не ошибался

Comment: @DreamChild:
>>Без обид, но начните с названия

Если у и придераться, то не к буковке "а" в "ассАмблер", а более детальней. Нет такого языка программирования "ассемблер". Ассемблер это программа, которая понимает мнемоники и переводит в машинные инструкции. Есть "язык ассемблера",т.е. тот диалект который понимает ассемблер. Это если быть совсем точным

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. В 2004-м году была популярна рассылка "Низкоуровневое программирование это просто". Настоятельно рекомендую начать изучать ассемблер именно с чтения этой рассылки.
2. Начните читать цикл статей по взлому программ и распаковке [Уроки Рикардо Нарваха](http://pro.dtn.ru/cr.html)

Этого будет достаточно, чтобы после прочтения этих первых познаний смогли ответить самому себе на вопрос "следует ли продолжать?" и также поймете сами, что конкретно Вам нужно!

Comment: А ссылку можно на ту рассылку? А то я сейчас искал и они с разным материалом и кстати там паскаль используется?

Comment: Нет! Pascal там не используется. К сожалению эта рассылка 2004-го года, автор Serrgio / HI-TECH.

Comment: @sys_dev,[Это][1] не она?
А вот [это][2] кажется оно, но все ли там статьи?


  [1]: http://subscribe.ru/catalog/comp.soft.prog.hitech?pos=7
  [2]: http://allasm.ru/low_prog.php

Comment: Да это именно этот чувак писал! ;) Вроде где-то тут http://subscribe.ru/ , должно быть

Answer (score 5):

По поводу портируемости/переносимости

> Что-то я не понял насчет переносимого/непереносимого ассамблера от мелкософта или ещё чего.

- Во-первых, для синтаксиса языка ассемблера нет **единого** стандарта. Для ассемблера x86 есть два типа синтаксиса: [Intel](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81) и [AT&T](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81). AT&T используется в основном под *nix системами (в частности, в ассемблере gas). Intel-синтаксис используется и под *nix, и win (ассемблеры masm, tasm, nasm, fasm, и др.)
- Кроме различия синтаксиса, у каждого ассемблера фактически свой синтаксис макросов (кроме masm и tasm - они какое-то время развивались параллельно, частично совместимы между собой), всяких служебных инструкций типа импорта, это делает невозможным компиляцию исходника для одного ассемблера другим ассемблером.
- [MASM](http://www.masm32.com/) (Macro Assembler) от Microsoft. компилирует только под Windows (хотя на просторах интернета можно найти версию под dos). Синтаксис Intel. Исходный код закрыт.
- Turbo Assembler от фирмы Borland. Не рекомендуется к использованию, т.к. уже давно не поддерживается. Существует компилятор под Windows и DOS. Используется синтаксис Intel, в основном схож с синтаксисом masm, но в каких-то деталях может различаться (100% точной информацией не владею). Исходный код закрыт.
- [Nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) (The Netwide Assembler). Компилирует под `*`nix и Windows. Синтаксис Intel, но есть отличия от masm и tasm. В Википедии утверждается, что под `*`nix конкурирует с ассемблером gas. Исходный код открыт, на данный момент распространяется под упрощенной лицензией BSD (Ранее LGPL).
- [Fasm](http://flatassembler.net/) (flat assembler) от независимого разработчика Tomasz Grysztar. Базируется на синтаксисе Intel, испытал влияние синтаксиса Nasm. Исходный код открыт, вариант лицензии BSD.
- GAS (GNU Assembler) - входит в пакет GNU Binutils. Цитирую Википедию, "Кроссплатформенная программа, запускается и компилирует код для многочисленных процессорных архитектур". Синтаксис AT&T (хотя есть режим поддержки синтаксиса от Intel). Исходный код открыт, лицензия GPL 3.

Резюмирую: программу (даже какой-нибудь Hello World), написанную например для ассемблера Masm в общем случае нельзя скомпилировать fasm'ом, и уж тем более gas'ом.

От себя под Windows рекомендую использовать MASM, либо fasm.

---

От себя конкретно про **fasm** могу сказать:

**fasm** на мой взгляд удобнее чем другие варианты (особенно для обучения), не нужно запоминать/записывать кучу ключей компиляции, тип готового бинарника определяется по исходнику, компилируется без отдельного этапа линковки, просто через `fasm файл.asm`.