# С какого языка ассемблера проще начать изучение на Windows 10 x64?

Tags: ассемблер

Основной мой стек завязан на C#, но т.к. проект большой, имеет много зависимостей и требует серьезной оптимизации, то периодически нужно

- Лезть в unsafe блоки
- Проверять адреса DLL
- Читать\использовать код на C\C++
- В некоторых случаях и разбираться в работе IL.

Если это важно, то по шарпу оцениваю себя как миддла, а в C\C++ чуть лучше, чем Hello World.

Собственно, для лучшего понимания IL (просто для себя) я и хочу понимать ассемблерный код.

Для примера скачал SASM и пытаюсь писать простейшие Hello World на fasm\nasm. Но часто код из статей с интернета не работает. Хотелось бы лучше понимать суть.

Comment: вы примеры должны искать точно для той ОС в которой будете тестировать, ввод/вывод например будет радикально отличаться для linux и windows, а на языке высокого уровня это зачастую одинаково выглядит

Comment: fasm или nasm - вполне нормальный вариант. Примеры соответственно нужно конкретно под них искать, и именно под вашу систему. SASM - это узкоспециализированная среда, только для обучения, аналогично рандомный пример для windows на нем не заработает. Можно взять просто fasm с его редактором или писать в любом редакторе, компилировать через командную строку.

Comment: В целом fasm на мой взгляду удобнее чем другие варианты (особенно для обучения), не нужно запоминать/записывать кучу ключей компиляции, тип готового бинарника определяется по исходнику, компилируется без отдельного этапа линковки, просто через `fasm файл.asm`

Comment: `gcc -S t.c` создает файл `t.s` с ассемблерным кодом. По-моему этот ассемблер называется att. Вот на нем и пиши

Comment: ну можно и интеловский `gcc -S -masm=intel`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [С чего начать изучение ассемблера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/275784/%d0%a1-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: ^ В общем-то, с 2013 года ничего глобально не изменилось

Answer (score -1):

Возьми книгу "Программирование на ассемблере х64. От начального уровня до профессионального использования AVX" и не парься.